# Java Writing multiple HashMaps to file

Tags: java

I am basically trying to write multiple (12, specifically) HashMap dictionaries to a local file and then retrieve them. So far I manage to do one however when I am trying to do more than one, i basically can not make it work. So any help to do this is appreciated. Here's my code so far:

```
private HashMap<String, List<String>> loadDict() {
    int month = Functions.getMonth();

    //load back in
    FileInputStream fis;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(statsFile);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
            //itemsDict = (HashMap) ois.readObject();
            Object whatisThis = (Object) ois.readObject();
            dictionaries.add(whatisThis);
        }
        ois.close();
        fis.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    itemsDict = (HashMap) dictionaries.get(month);
    System.out.println(itemsDict.get("cake"));
    return itemsDict;
}

private void setupDictionaries() {
    HashMap<String, List<String>> dictionary = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(statsFile);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
            oos.writeObject(dictionary);
        }
        oos.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
private void storeThis(String product, String price, String quantity, String date, List<List<String>> myContent) {//after set, replace dictionary in dictionaries array
    dictionaries.set(Functions.getMonth(), itemsDict);

    //save the dictionary to the overall statistics file
    FileOutputStream fos;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(statsFile);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
            oos.writeObject(dictionaries.get(i));
        }
        //oos.writeObject(itemsDict);
        oos.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

A bit of clarification: setupDictionaries is only called on the first run (to setup the file), otherwise loadDict() is called on runtime, to load all the dictionaries into an arraylist. From the arraylist, the correct object (hashmap) should be chosen and then cased to itemsDict as hashmap. 
storeThis() is called when a button is pressed, however I cut down the code to only relevant bits.

---

So I am trying to implement the JSON you have suggested, so far I've got:

```
private void setupDictionaries() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ArrayNode arrayNode = mapper.createArrayNode();
    JsonNode rootNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
    ArrayList<String> myThing = new ArrayList<String>();
    myThing.add("hi");
    myThing.add(".");

    itemsDict.put("cake", myThing);

    JsonNode childNode1 = mapper.valueToTree(itemsDict);
    ((ObjectNode) rootNode).set("Jan",  childNode1);
    JsonNode childNode2 = mapper.createObjectNode();
    ((ObjectNode) rootNode).set("obj2", childNode2);
    JsonNode childNode3 = mapper.createObjectNode();
    ((ObjectNode) rootNode).set("obj3", childNode3);
    String jsonString;
    try {
        jsonString = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(rootNode);
        System.out.println(jsonString);
        ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writer(new DefaultPrettyPrinter());
        writer.writeValue(new File(statsFile), jsonString);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e2.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Question, how would I be able to load this back? (only everything underneath Jan for example, to a hashmap)

```
private HashMap<String, List<String>> loadDict() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = mapper.readValue(new File(statsFile), new TypeReference<HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>>() {});
        System.out.println(map.get("Jan"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

With this code I would be able to load it, however I get this exception (because I have multiple hashmaps within the Json):

JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of java.util.HashMap: no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value

(I don't know how to put exceptions here)

My JSON:

> "{\r\n  \"Jan\" : {\r\n    \"cake\" : [ \"hi\", \".\" ]\r\n  },\r\n  \"obj2\" : { },\r\n  \"obj3\" : { }\r\n}"

So how would I be able to only load a specific month into a hashmap?

Comment: Could you elaborate on why you "can not make it work"? What's going wrong exactly?

Comment: Why not just import/export to JSON?

Comment: Maybe you are writing 13  HashMap dictionaries instead of 12?

Comment: So 12 objects get written to the file, and when I add something to one of the dictionaries and then write everything back, the values are stored. However, when I try to use a different dictionary, it retains all the values from the previous one. Basically it behaves as if it was the same dictionary written in 12 times, except the values are only stored once...

Comment: I think the `ObjectInputStream` expects to read a single `Object` from its stream (while the `ObjectOuputStream` has no problem writing multiple objects to the same file if you ask it to), so you should either write each dictionary to its own file, or write a `List<HashMap>` to your single file which you'll be able to retrieve and use to reinstanciate your multiple dictionaries

Comment: You are writing multiple Objects to a single file. Not working. Not unless you extend `ObjectOutputStream` and overwrite at least the `writeStreamHeader()` method. If you want to write the Objects into files, it would be easier to create 1 file for every Object. Or think about alternative storing methods like xml/json or a database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely use Json format, consider that this format (which is plain text) give you the freedom to edit the file with an editor.

I'll suggest to use [Jackson](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core) library.

You have just to create an `ObjectMapper` and use it to serialise and deserialise the json. Reading the [documentation](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-objectmapper.html#reading-json-from-a-file) I see you can also read and write json files.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
```

For example this line would convert a Json String into a `Map`;

```
Map<String, Object> map = objectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
```

And you can convert a map into a Json even easier:

```
objectMapper.writeValueAsString(json)
```

The rest of your problem remain read and write the files.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Could you please give me an example of how I would be able to achieve what I am aiming for using Jackson? I've been digging in the documentation with nothing so far.

Comment: @peterxz read your map `File file = new File("data/file.json"); Map<String, Object> map = objectMapper.readValue(file, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});`

Comment: @peterxz Write your map: `objectMapper.writeValue(
    new FileOutputStream("data/file.json"), map);`

Comment: I've not tried, but I don't think it could be easier :)

Comment: Thank you! I have edited my question, if you could please help me out a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

When you've got multiple independently growing lists or equivalent and are trying to handle storing within a single file, the question is how would you want to handle overlap.

What would also matter is how frequently you write versus how frequently the data is read. If its mostly reads and long pauses are fine, then go for using json format (every time an edit is made then you have to re-write the whole json and the reads will have to wait until the operation is complete).

However if read and write would be approximately equal in measure then I think you'll need to consider splitting up the data into sequential sections - similar to what a database might do it.

===============================================================================

For example :

```
meta-data + 1*1024 bytes of 01st map 
meta-data + 1*1024 bytes of 02nd map 
meta-data + 1*1024 bytes of 03rd map 
..
meta-data + 1*1024 bytes of 12th map 
meta-data + 2*1024 bytes of 01st map 
meta-data + 2*1024 bytes of 02nd map 
..
meta-data + 2*1024 bytes of 12th map 
meta-data + 3*1024 bytes of 01st map 
...
and so on..
```

The meta-data will tell you whether to continue to the next section for any given map's data.

===============================================================================

You would also have to consider things like whether you are using hard-disk (sequential access) or SSD (random-access) and then decide which approach you want to go with.

Comment: There should be no problems using this method performance wise, I am just not sure how to do it. I can't say why I want to do it this way, however there is a reason I have to store data in this manner.

Comment: Since you seem to be using java, you can either have a bean-class that has an array of maps and perform a json-serialize and json-deserialize the same. Else instead of a bean you can also simply have a  list of 12 maps and then perform the transformation.

Comment: I do have 12 maps, however I am unable to load back from the file. I can write to the json file perfectly well, but when I try to convert from the json file to hashmap object, I get an exception because it is trying to convert the whole file to a map object, but I only want to convert a section (because the file looks like this: Jan: <hashmap>, Feb: <hashmap> etc, and I only want to load the hashmap itself for a given montH)

Comment: Then have a map of maps (or a property file). The first map will contain keys jan-dec. The values will be maps with key-value pairs. With regard to the exception, this works for me :  `mapper.readValue(input, HashMap.class)` .